# In scala, how can I find the size of an array element

Tags: arrays, scala, size, element

Scala newbie, Have an array where one element is an array:

```
val aaa = Array("a", "b", Array(1, 2, 3), "c")
```

This works:

```
In []: aaa(2)
Out[]: Array(1, 2, 3)
```

This works:

```
In []: Array(1, 2, 3).size
Out[]:3
```

This does not:

```
In []: aaa(2).size
Out[]:
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:15: error: value size is not a member of                     
java.io.Serializable
          aaa(2).size
                 ^
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Find out type of `aaa` variable

Comment: It seems to be an Array

Comment: It's not a good idea to have an array with multiple types like in your example. Why did you want to do ?

Comment: The type of `aaa` is `Array[java.io.Serializable]` So, when you do `aaa(2)` you get an element of type `java.io.Serializable` which does not have a method size defined on it.

Comment: I have an rdd that comes that way, eventually I want to zip all non array elements with the array element for that I need the arrays element size first, that the way I usually do it on python

Comment: Some of the answers hint at this but your underlying issue is that you're mixing incompatible types in the array. Since Scala is a statically-typed language (unlike python, which is why it worked for that), the compiler has to find some type that everything in the array is a member of, and ends up with java.io.Serializable. The fix is not to cast the arrays or somesuch, but not not mix incompatible types. It is very rarely necessary. Please explain more  about your use-case and why you think you have an RDD too that mixes types in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create an array using the following literal

```
val aaa = Array("a", "b", Array(1, 2, 3), "c")
```

Since the type of the elements are different, the array `aaa` type is created with **java.io.Serializable**

```
aaa: Array[java.io.Serializable] = Array(a, b, Array(1, 2, 3), c)
```

So when you refer back the 2nd element, the type of the reference will be of `Serializable` and there is no size property in it. So we need to explicity typecast/convert the 2nd element to Array using **asInstanceOf**. As shown below

```
 if (aaa(2).isInstanceOf[Array[Int]]) 
       aaa(2).asInstanceOf[Array[Int]].size
```

Comment: Avoid uncheck casts. That's dangerous and "code smell".

Answer (score 3):

Most common type for your declaration is serializable

```
val aaa = Array("a", "b", Array(1, 2, 3), "c")
Array[java.io.Serializable]
```

If you want to use it with size, you can explicitly define:

```
val aaa: Array[Seq[Any]] = Array("a", "b", Array(1, 2, 3), "c")
```

all Strings will be converted to Sequences of Chars in this case.

Comment: This is good since it requires no conditional code after the val is set.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not a good idea to mix arrays and non-arrays (and, in general, elements of different types) in an array. Sometimes, there are corner cases, when you can't get around having to do that, but as a rule, arrays (and other scala containers) are meant to hold homogenous types.

So, I would recommend to begin with splitting your array into two:

```
val (arrays, nonArrays) =  
  Array("a", "b", Array(1, 2, 3), "c").partition { 
     case a: Array[_] => true
     case _ => false
  }
```

Now, you can easily tell the lengths of all your arrays:

```
  arrays.foreach { println(_.size) }
```

If you wanted to preserve the original position information, you could zip the original array with indexes first:

```
 val (arrays, nonArrays) = Array("a", "b", Array(1, 2, 3), "c")
   .zipWithIndex
   .partition {
      case (a: Array[_], _) => true
      case _ => false
   }

 arrays.foreach { 
   case (array, index) => 
     prinlnt(s"Array length at index $index is ${array.size}")
 }
```

Comment: `arrays.foreach { println(_.size) }` line is not working. Because _ is still referring to type `java.io.Serializable` and `size` is not a member of Serializable type.  FYI after executing first block `arrays` refer to `arrays:Array[java.io.Serializable] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3))`.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work -- still Serializable :(